# Merging two API calls together with JSON

Tags: python, json

I am pulling JSON data from a GET request over an API and I am unable to get the responses to join together. I am new to dictionaries and indexes (and python for that manner).

The API data is the same, it is just a different page number. Able to verify via the eclipse debugger. I am able to confirm that each API call is able to pull the data it needs as well.

```
#pulls from the API
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

obj_json = response.content
objLoader = json.loads(obj_json)
obj1 = objLoader

#url changes to page 2
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

obj_json = response.content
obj1 = json.loads(obj_json)

newObj = dict(obj1.items() + obj2.items())
#I have also tried the following:
#dict(obj1.items() | obj2.items())
```

In the end I'd like obj2 to be appended to obj1.

```
#Let's say obj1 has:
indexes[0][1]
#and obj2 has 
indexes [0][1]
#I'd like obj1 to have 
indexes[0][1][2][3]
```

The obj1 & 2 item data is structured like this:

```
obj1/2: dict u'count': 25370, u'items': [{..........}]

__len__: int: 508
count: int 25370
items: <type 'list'>: [{...}]
page: int
pages: int
```

Thank you, and let me know if you need more information!

Comment: Aside: `requests` has a shortcut for parsing the json: `obj1 = response.json()`.

Comment: Do you need to get a valid API answer, or just get all items?

Comment: Please produce a [mcve] with no extraneous code. Get rid of the calls to `requests`. Get rid of the calls to `json`. Just create two `dict` objects, and show how you're trying to merge them, what the result is, and what the result you'd hoped for was. This should be a short (5-10 line), complete program that we can run and reproduce your results.

Comment: How wold I produce the dictionary test data @Robᵩ? I will be more than glad to do this. 

Let's say the first response goes to 49 elements, I'ld like the second response to be appended to the 50th element-98th element

Comment: By running `requests` and `json` and printing the result. Then get rid of all of the terms that aren't pertinent to your question.

Comment: something like this then obj1[printResults], obj2[printResults]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
url_header_list = [
    (url1, headers1),
    (url2, headers2),
    (url3, headers3),
    ...
]

items = []
# You can change your headers and url in any way you want, not just like that
for url, headers in url_header_list:
    # And this you need to do for each pair of url and headers
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    items.extend(response['items'])
```

`items` will contain all the items from each response.

Answer (score 2):

Lets assume your JSON response looks like this:

```
{"ID":1,"name":"Donald","first-name":"Trump","age":25,"hobbies":["tweet","hunting",{"sports":["volley-ball","golf"]}],"address":{}}
```

For Obj2:

```
{"ID":2,"name":"Barack","first-name":"Obama","age":25,"hobbies":["reading","cinema",{"sports":["volley-ball","badminton"]}],"address":{}}
```

You need to convert the JSON response to dict, and then append this dictionary to an array of objects:

```
 [{"ID":1,"name":"Donald","first-name":"Trump","age":25,"hobbies":["tweet","hunting",{"sports":["volley-ball","golf"]}],"address":{}},{"ID":2,"name":"Barack","first-name":"Obama","age":25,"hobbies":["reading","cinema",{"sports":["volley-ball","badminton"]}],"address":{}}]
```

Comment: This is what the data looks like

`{u'count': 25373, u'items': [{u'closedBy': None, u'cc': None, u'number': 98976, u'owner': {u'firstName': u'joe', u'lastName': u'Shmoe', u'email': u'joe.shmoe@this.com', u'phone': None, u'type': u'user', u'id': 74336}, u'id': 432345, u'createdAt': u'2016-03-24T17:16:05Z', u'subject': u'Mail', u'folderId': 1234323, u'spam': False, u'createdByType': u'customer', u'isDraft': False, u'source': {u'via': u'customer', u'type': u'email'}, u'draft': False, u'preview': u'some text. \xa0more text.', u'type': u'phone', u'status': u'pending', u'tags': [u'1507']...`

Comment: If that's what it looks like now, what do you want it to look like after your program alters it?