# merg data of two api in python using json

Tags: python

Check this page https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo Here you will find two api’s one for posts and comments https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/posts https://my-json-server.typicode.com/typicode/demo/comments

What you need to do is write a code which will read data from both these api’s and assign comment to its respective post and finally return an object (dict/json) which has the combined data of both posts/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can see this question is same as you want:

[Merging two API calls together with JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36205458/merging-two-api-calls-together-with-json)

And this article  explain that:

https://www.codespeedy.com/how-to-merge-two-json-files-in-python/